# Impacto de troca - MyISAM por InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

Em um médio banco de dados (~2GB) MySQL que está todo com o engine MyISAM. Realizando a conversão para InnoDB, qual será o impacto em meu sistema? Posso simplesmente converter pelo phpMyAdmin, por exemplo?

Alguém já passou por esta experiência?

Comment: Para bases pequenas como essa, não haverá uma perda de performance grande, provavelmente a base ou pelo menos os índices cabem todos em memória... realmente acredito que só tem a ganhar indo para myisam... a não ser que tenha uma unica tabela gigantesca e acessada constantemente com pouca escrita... nesse caso melhor deixar em myisam

Comment: Entendi... Meu maior problema é casos de select demorado em tabelas onde simultaneamente é feito um update. Neste caso, o update fica aguardando e toda a tabela trava (locked). Pelo que entendi, o InnoDB trava somente a linha. Certo?

Comment: sim.. vai pra inno é a solução... myisam faz table lock mesmo.. momentaneamente sugiro que faça um delayed insert se a consistência cronológica não for importante

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como tudo em quase tudo **"Depende"**
Myisam é mais rápida para *consultas lineares* e tem muito poucas checagens em inserts e updates, tornando mais *rápida para a escrita.*
Innodb é muito mais robusta e garantida em termos de *consistência dos dados*, como chaves estrangeiras que funcionam de verdade

**Avalie**

1º: precisa de velocidade muito alta e não tem referencias difíceis de recuperar entre tabelas? (sim: myisam +1, não: innodb +1)

2º: a partição onde se encontram a base esta em um volume em RAID? (sim: impacto negativo da escrita do innodb diminui, innodb +1)

3º: Muitas escritas concorrentes em uma mesma tabela ou linha?(sim: innodb +1,não: myisam +1)

existem muitos outros fatores mais para computar... mas esses acredito que sejam os mais impactantes.

Quanto a migração, é braçal, não adianta... pode(vai!) ter problemas com falta de consistência passando de myisam para innodb, e vai ter que corrigir na mão para ter garantia de que tudo foi importado como deveria...

obs: myisam é mais rapida quando o tamanho das tabelas é fixo.. do contrario pode ser inferior.. (exemplo uso de varchar sempre)

Comment: Perfeito Breno, poderia me dar um exemplo do primeiro item?

Comment: o exemplo que um cara da SUN me deu quando o mysql ainda era deles.. operadoras telefônicas usando MySQL para consulta de numero de telefone e central a qual pertencia, é uma lista quilométrica e com muito mais consulta do que escrita... se não fosse a portabilidade do numero talvez um ldap fosse a solução ideal.. mas hoje em dia não é.. então muitas operadoras usam myisam, no qual eles possuem o cadastro dos clientes para reconstruir a tabela de modo trivial se necessário, obs innodb corrompido é adeus a base, restore backup mais logbinario.. myisam tem o myisamcheck

Comment: Entendi... E no caso de +500 tabelas, por exemplo? Seria recomendável fazer parte MyISAM e parte InnoDB?

Estou fazendo um levantamento para uma empresa desta questão.

Comment: Da forma como está redigido, parece que InnoDB tem performance ruim para READ. Isso não é verdade. Ele pode ser _um pouco mais lento_, mas definitivamente isso não impede de ser usado. Não por acaso que o padrão de engine há anos é InnoDB em vez de MyISAM. A não ser que tenha-se certeza do porque usar MyISAM, em 2014 é melhor usar InnoBD.

Comment: rsrsrs... Todas ótimas respostas...

Seria possível pontuar mais alguns itens para estabelecer +1 ou -1 e firmar, no meu caso, se é recomendável ou não utilizar?

Comment: no seu caso é innodb a solução... muitos inserts em uma unica tabela que tem leitura constante..

Answer (score 1):

Tem dois tipos de impacto, o durante a migração e o após durante o uso.

### Impacto durante o uso

Praticamente tudo que o MyISAM faz, o InnoDB faz, em especial se você usar versões  mais novas do MySQL ou do MariaDB. Não deve notar diferença significativa, e se sua quantidade de writes é significativa, deve ter uma melhora percepivel.

Não obstante, se você fizer no mesmo servidor que tem o MyISAM, provavelmente vai ter problemas de performance porque seu servidor pode estar otimizado para MyISAM e não InnoDB. Certifique-se de conferir se a performance não sofreu penalidade e, se foi, leve a sério configuração do servidor

Outro ponto é que você vai provavelmetne vai precisar de mais espaço em disco, em especial se tiver muitas chaves primárias e indices.

### Impacto durante a migração

Isso vai depender da sua estrutura de dados, mas estamos falando de minutos de downtime, ou mesmo horas. Tudo depende de como é sua estrutura de tabelas e da potência do seu servidor. Teste fora do seu servidor para ver se o tempo de parada é aceitável, e, se não for, leia a respeito de como otimizar o InnoDB para conversão inicial, algumas dicas podem diminuir tempo de 30 horas para 30 minutos em bancos de dados enormes e não otimizados para usar toda memória disponível.